# PHP: Finding MIME TYPE of given link to the file

Tags: php, request, mime, head

So, I'm trying to forbid linking certain file types to my page..

Situation: User pastes link, and if for example it is a ZIP file, it won't work.

I tried head requests with cURL and get_headers and it has a problem.. if I check, I get a result, but if I only change extension of a file, it gets me incorrect information, based on a extension (not checking MIME).

So my question was - is there a way to truly find type of file with given URL ?

Tnx :)

Comment: To "truly" find it, download it and check with e.g. the `file` command.

Comment: not with out retrieving the whole file to be checked

Comment: I don't get your remark about changing the extension of a file. Wouldn't you get a 404 if you change its name? Show us what you tried.

Comment: no no, I change extension on server, and ofcourse request url on my local script, request is okay - no 404

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for you to detect malicious content without downloading it yourself and checking its bytes.

Note that this will probably put your server at risk.

Comment: probably put server at risk.. yeah, and the fact that I have to dl whole file.. :/

Comment: And if they use short link URLs like bit.ly, you have to deal with another step of indirection because the answer to your HEAD request probably is a redirect... To another shortlink service... and another... and another... and you might end up at one of the filesharing hosters without any method of actually checking the file itself.